# flickr api: how to know which albums the image belong to

Tags: flickr

I am getting a list of photos using

https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search

It gives a json with an array of photos.

I also want to know to which albume each photo belong to (if at all)

Because when i open https://www.flickr.com/photos/147875968@N08/44811952245/in/photostream/#hare it shows `This photo is in 1 album`  and says Yellow Cat

Similary is there any way to know which albums this photo is in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can use [flickr.photos.getAllContexts](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getAllContexts.html) to find the photosets to which a photo belongs.

Comment: but why dont they supply this data along with each photo rather than getting it again in a separate api